# It's cleanup time but How?

Tags: permissions

A user has left the company and I been finding her many different places from main portal http://portal.inhouse.ca to all the site collections, sub sites and SP groups..

Is there a powershell way to delete her from everywhere? (domain\jsmith)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the script below, it "Remove / Delete users from all sites and site collections within a web application.":
http://blog.isaacblum.com/2011/02/24/remove-delete-users-from-all-sites-and-site-collections-within-a-web-application/

Comment: No problem, all common tasks are already implemented by someone and blogged:) You just need to know what to solution is right and use it.

Answer (score 4):

To loop through all the sites in a portal use foreach. sample below

```
$portalUrl = Read-Host "Enter Site URL" 
$rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($portalUrl)
$spWebApp = $rootSite.WebApplication 

foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)
{

}
```

Implement above foreach code for below if you need to go through each web in a portal.

```
function RemoveUser([string]$Site, [string]$SiteCollection, [string]$User) {

    # GAC

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web") | Out-Null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") | Out-Null

    # Connect To Sharepoint

    $SPSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($Site)
    $OpenWeb = $SPSite.OpenWeb($SiteCollection)

    # Check if User Exists in Site

    if ($OpenWeb.SiteUsers | Where {$_.LoginName -eq $User}) {
        $User = $OpenWeb.SiteUsers | Where {$_.LoginName -eq $User}
        $OpenWeb.SiteUsers.Remove($User)

        Write-Host "User: $User Successfully Removed from Site: $Site/$SiteCollection"
    } else {
    Write-Host "User: $User Does not exist on Site: $Site/$SiteCollection"
    }
    $SPSite.Dispose()
    $OpenWeb.Dispose()
}
```

Usage:

```
PS > Remove-SPUser.ps1 -Site http://wss -SiteCollection Test -User Domain\User

PS > Remove-SPUser.ps1 -help
```

Comment: Yours is good too. Almost exactly same as what default suggested. Thanks